# How to pause Jquery Cycle plugin mid animation (on hover)

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am using Jquery cycle and have it scrolling horizontally continuously.I would like the animation to stop when a user hovers over. I have this working sorta via the "pause:1" option with the plugin, but it doesn't pause until it has cycled to the next image, which is slow. I would like it to pause mid-animation when a user hovers, so even if it's halfway between images, then resume on mouseout. Is this possible?

My code:

```
$('.gallery .continuous').each(function(index, element) {   
    $(element).cycle({ 
        fx:'scrollHorz',                
        continuous: 1,
        speed:10000,
        timeout:0,
        easing: 'linear',
        pause:1,
        pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just thought I'd check again, has anybody got an idea on how to do this?!

Answer (score 2):

Hi Desmond you can try this in your javascript. Put it in document ready

```
    $('.gallery .continuous').hover(
function(){
$(this).cycle('pause');  //Pauses the cycle on hover
},
function(){
$(this).cycle('resume'); // Resumes the cycle when mouse is outside div
});
```

I Hope it will work fine for you.

Comment: Check it out, if you are using the same plugin, as I expect http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pause.html

Comment: Thanks Paritosh. I have the gallery setup as a continuous left to right animation and I wanted it to stop midway through a cycle if the user hovers - those ones only stop at the end of the animation.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="slider">
        <img class="images" src="1.jpg">
        <img class="images" src="2.jpg">
        <img class="images" src="3.jpg">
        <img class="images" src="4.jpg">
    </div>

<!-- for example above mentioned is your html with container with id "slider"

then cycle code will be like that -->


    <script>
    //this is your cycling code!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      $('#slider').cycle({ 
        fx:      'scrollHorz', 
        timeout:   200,
        speed:   1000,
        next: '.right',
        prev: '.left'
    });

//if you want to pause you need to use .cycle("pause") for e.g:

//on mouseover.

        $('#slider').mouseover(function(){
            $('#slider').cycle('pause');
        });


    //and continue on mouse out

        $('#slider').mouseout(function(){
            $('#slider').cycle('resume');
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd like to suggest that instead of pasting the whole code, simply type an answer and show code _and explain it_!